# product ID list for In App billing

Tags: android, billing

Is there a possibility to obtain a list of products ID defined for In App billing from the application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The android marketplace allows for exporting the list of product ID as a CSV but it can't be done from the application. What you can do is manage a list of product IDs on your own server and query that from the application.